# Robocopy Access Denied Error 5 From Powershell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am copying files from my build server to a web server on Windows Server 2016. I am running the following from PowerShell. I am running this script with an administer account which has read/write access to the destination directory.

```
robocopy $Path\Items $_\Items /Sec /copy:DT /MIR /NDL /NS /NP /MT /w:1 /r:1 /R:20 2>&1 | out-host
```

I get the following error

> ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory
>   \SOMEPATH\Data\Items\  Access is denied.

Comment: What is not clear about the error? The user running `robocopy` does not have permissions to access the file.

Comment: but i gave the user full permission

Comment: the user is also a local admin

Comment: It's a legit question, I have the same problem, the remote folder is accessible and can be listed from PowerShell but the copy fails with access denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ensure that you open your powershell session as an administrator (runas)
- Also check the NTFS permission on the destination path and not only the security permissions.
- If you are using a DFS path you should be better with the UNC path of the actual servername.